# Creating singleton object, best way

Tags: java, singleton

I want to create a singleton object and I found 3 ways, which one is better and why are others bad. The constructor is assumed to be private.

Method 1:

```
class ClassX{  
   private static ClassX objX = null;

      static{
          objX = new ClassX();
      }

   //get objX method
 }
```

Method 2:

```
 class ClassX{  
   private static ClassX objX = new ClassX();

   //get objX method
 }
```

Method 3:

```
 class ClassX{  
   private static ClassX objX = null;

   public ClassX getInstance(){
      if(objX == null)
          return new ClassX();
      else
          return objX;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Consider using an `enum`. Also, lazy vs eager considerations are application specific.

Comment: I only see method 3 as singleton pattern :/

Comment: Use dependency injection instead.

Comment: @Kossel Then I suggest you might want to get your eyes checked out :) All three snippets are singletons, method 3 is the only *lazily initialised* one. That is, assuming there's a `private` constructor, otherwise none of them guarantee a singleton. (Depends on how you define that term: an object of which only one instance *is* ever created; or an object of which only one instance *can* ever be created.)

Comment: @Kossel: Why are other two not singleton? They also produce only one instance in a life time.

Comment: Yup, the constructor is assumed to be private. I have mentioned that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Comment: @millimoose doesn't singleton mean "an object of which only one instance can ever be created"?

Comment: @Harke Not necessarily. I maintain that it can mean both, depending on if you use the term in a design (pattern) context, or in an implementation one. That is, if I use dependency injection, and in my bootstrap code only create one instance of a component, and inject only this instance into every object that needs it as a collaborator, I'd say that this component is still a singleton even though there's nothing preventing anyone from (erroneously) creating another instance of it.

Comment: I always use method 3, but didn't know it's lazy initialised one... I just read wikipedia, and they give pretty good description of each style

Comment: Anyway, isn't the simplest safe way to do this `public static final INSTANCE = new Foo();`?

Comment: A lot of users/answerers here seem to have no utter idea what exactly the singleton design pattern tries to solve. If you are such one, carefully read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern. The "best way" to implement it is either the Pugh or the Enum solution. Depending on the concrete functional requirements which the OP didn't tell any word about, the *right* way to achieve *that* functional requirement is however more than often [just create one](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne).

Comment: @BalusC I wish I could upvote that comment more than once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use an enum like this:-

```
public enum Foo
{
   INSTANCE;
}
```

Also check out the related answer:- [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Quoting few lines from the [Enforce the Singleton Property with a Private Constructor or an enum Type](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883?pgno=3) which Stephen Denne has used in  the above answer:-

> This approach is functionally equivalent to the public field approach,
>   except that it is more concise, provides the serialization machinery
>   for free, and provides an ironclad guarantee against multiple
>   instantiation, even in the face of sophisticated serialization or
>   reflection attacks. While this approach has yet to be widely adopted,
>   a **single-element enum type is the best way to implement a singleton**.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ClassX {
    private static volatile ClassX instance = null;

    private ClassX() { }

    public ClassX getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (ClassX.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new ClassX();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do people still try to use DCL in Java? Or did they fix the memory model.

Comment: @Kayaman I believe they did. EDIT: Yup, in Java 5: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Comment: DCL is recommended by Joshua Bloch's book, "Effective Java."

Comment: Okay, seems I'm a bit outdated on the memory model these days. But it still applies only to lazy-loading singletons, although I think a lot of people erroneously think that a singleton should always be lazy loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Method  3 is not thread-safe, meaning that if multiple callers come in at the same time, you can end up with more than one singleton.  Method 1 and 2 will work and are essentially the same thing.  You might want to consider this example, using [double check locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking):

```
Class ClassX{  
   private static ClassX objX = null;

   public static ClassX getInstance(){
      if(objX == null)
          synchronized(this) {
              if(objX == null)
              objX = new ClassX();
          }

      return objX;
   }
}
```

It may seem silly, but double-checked locking is thread safe and far cheaper than using a `synchronized` version of `getInstance()`, which makes absolutely sure that you will only ever have 1 `ClassX` instance.  Also, this allows you to pass data into `getInstance()` should you choose to use it as a factory or service locator who's job it is to create or store singletons.

Comment: How can you use "this" in static block?

Answer (score 0):

create a static final private instance & access it using a static getter and the construtor is private ofcourse.

```
private static final ClassX classX = new ClassX();

public static ClassX getInstance(){
  return classX;
}
```

or use dependency injection.

Comment: why downvote? what is the issue with this approach?

Comment: Who knows :) It could be your missing ClassX word in first line))) (correct it, please)

Comment: don't wail, i upvoted, you have 0 :-P

Answer (score 0):

You do not need lazy initialisation:

```
class Foo {
    public static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();
    private Foo();
}
```

This probably won't resist serialization or reflection, but it should be good enough w/r/t thread safety. (Of course, you could also just create only one instance as I've implied in my comments.)